# Show values of reactive form in other component

Tags: angular

The situation is that I have several components such as component A in which there is a reactive form. Data from the forms are collected in one service. Now I would like to preview this form in component B, but after changing the path to routerLink="/componentB" data from the service and component A are no longer available. Below is the code:

Component A

```
  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) {

    this.step = this.formBuilder.group({
      field: [''],
    });
    this.formService.stepReady(this.step, 'one');
  }
```

Service

```
  private stepOneSource: Subject<FormGroup> = new Subject();
  stepOne: Observable<FormGroup> = this.stepOneSource.asObservable();
  
    mainForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    one: this.formBuilder.group({
      field: [''],
    }),
  
    constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {

    this.stepOne.subscribe(form =>
      form.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
        this.mainForm.controls.one.patchValue(val);
      })
    );
  
    stepReady(form: FormGroup, part) {
    switch (part) {
      case 'one': {
        this.stepOneSource.next(form);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: when you realize the stepOneSource.next, the component B is not, so can not received any thing. I sugessted that simply store in a **variable** of the service the formGroup `this.formService.formVariable=this.step `, and in ngOnInit of component B get the variable `this.stepFromComponentB=this.formService.formVariable`. NOTE: If only want to share the "value", pass only the value of the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `BehaviourSubject` when the value needs to be stored.

`private stepOneSource: Subject<FormGroup> = new BehaviourSubject();`

Comment: This is helpful. The problem was that I was reseting componentB by setting up again providers : [FormService]
Now I have a problem that after returning from componentB back to componentA the form is empty.